# Has Many :through Multiple Assignment, updating meta fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models which have a `has_many :through` relationship

**Model-1**: `BusinessClassification`

**Model-2**: `Territory`

```
BusinessClassification 
has_many :territories, through: :BusinessClassificationTerritory
```

`BusinessClassificationTerritory` has fields like `created_at`, `updated_at` along with `business_classification_id`, `territory_id`.

I am using multiple assignment like

```
@business_classification.territories << @territories
```

How do I updated the fields `created_at` and `updated_at` while assigning multiple `territories`?

Comment: Look at [`touch`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/touch) method.